LXD with multiple GPUs
I'm playing around with LXD for the first time and my goal is to host three VMs each with a dedicated GPU. I am able to pass any one of the GPUs through to the guest VM (Windows) however when I start up the second VM with its own GPU the server locks up after about 30 seconds. Normally, I would consult a log to try and get to the bottom of this issue however, I'm either not looking in the correct place or the system locks up before getting to the point of logging. When the system locks up, there is no way to interact with it beyond holding the power button.

I have configured the CPU to support the IOMMU feature in BIOS
I have enabled the IOMMU feature in GRUBs boot configuration
I have confirmed that each of the GPUs are in their own IOMMU groups, and that the CPU does infact support IOMMU.
I have configured the drivers for the GPUs to use VFIO-PCI on boot soas to eliminate any issues with driver switching.
I have been tailing the /var/log/messages and /var/log/dmesg
Monitoring top doesn't seem to point to any particular process eating up all of the CPU
I have swapped which devices are assigned to which vms, doesn't seem to fix the problem.
I am able to run both VMs at the same time if I remove the GPU assignment from one of them.
I am using unique PCI addresses for the VMs.
I am starting the vms through the web UI.


OS: Ubuntu Server 22.04, fresh install before this, all packages
updated.
CPU: 2x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3
GPUs: 3x NVIDIA Quadro RTX 4000
Chassis: CSE-118 Supermicro

My hunch is something to do with IOMMU groups or some sort of configuration within qemu that I haven't tried. Perhaps I need to assign particular CPU cores to each VM so that the group assignments are assigned to the same CPU (not sure how I'd even do that)? At this point I'd be happy just to get some error logs so I have something to go off of.

Guides I've consulted:

GPU data processing inside LXD (ubuntu.com)
LXD Reference GPU Devices (ubuntu.com)
GPU passthrough with libvirt qemu kvm (gentoo.org)
PCI Passthrough (proxmox.com)
Virtual machines with PCI passthrough on Ubuntu 20.04 (mathiashueber.com)
PCI passthrough via OVMF (archlinux.org)


After consulting with a LLM for about an hour, I found that the root cause was that I was allocating 102% of the hosts ram to my guest vms. I'm surprised that I was able to run both VMs at any point without the system crashing. I guess this just goes to show, check the basic things even if you're a couple weeks into trying to fix a problem.
